# My main content is being affected by something on the page, won't center properly

Tags: html, css, text, center

following a very good although basic tutorial, my content (the text between the header and the footer) won't center.

Ive tried to follow many tutorials for responsive image boxes (i.e. 3 in a row, and when resized to mobile it should be 1 by 1 as you scroll down) and I have failed miserably. Everything was going well up until now, and I have the feeling something bigger is affecting my whole page, Im sure this is simple for a lot of people, but I am dumbstruck.

Thanks in advance to anyone that can help, this is killing me.

This is my HTML (I am using a Dreamweaver template for the entire site, but this is not the template file, just an HTML created from the template).

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr"><!-- InstanceBegin template="/Templates/Template.dwt" codeOutsideHTMLIsLocked="false" -->

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/0e803ef49c.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style>@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap');</style>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="doctitle" -->
        <title>Holiday Rentals</title>
    <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->

    <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="head" -->
    <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
    
</head>

<body>

    
    <!-- Navigation Bar -->
    <nav>
        <input type="checkbox" id="check">
        <label for="check" class="checkbtn">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </label>
        <label class="logo">MALLORCA<span>NOW</span></label>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="active"href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Holiday Rentals</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">For Sale</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <!-- End Navigation Bar -->
    
    
    <!-- Main Content -->
    <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="main-content" -->  
    <div class="main-content">
        <div class="box-area">
            <div class="single-box">
                <div class="img-area"></div>
                <div class="img-text">
                    <span class="header-text">Azalea</span>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque scelerisque ut quam ac iaculis. Mauris.</p>
                </div>   
            </div>
            <div class="single-box">
                <div class="img-area"></div>
                <div class="img-text">
                    <span class="header-text">Canguila</span>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque scelerisque ut quam ac iaculis. Mauris.</p>
                </div>   
            </div>
            <div class="single-box">
                <div class="img-area"></div>
                <div class="img-text">
                    <span class="header-text">Iris</span>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque scelerisque ut quam ac iaculis. Mauris.</p>
                </div>   
            </div>
        </div>
    
    </div>
        

    


    
    <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
    <!-- End Main Content -->
    
    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer>
        <div class="footer-main-content">
            <div class="left box">
                <h2>About Us</h2>
                <div class="footer-content">
                    <p>Mallorca Now, established in 2010, specialise in Property Rentals, Sales and Management in the North East area of Mallorca, covering mainly Cala Ratjada, Cala Bona, Cala Millor and Cala Anguila (inc Porto Cristo Novo). </p>
                    <div class="social">
                        <a href="#"><span class="fab fa-facebook-f"></span></a>
                        <a href="#"><span class="fab fa-twitter"></span></a>
                        <a href="#"><span class="fab fa-instagram"></span></a>
                        <a href="#"><span class="fab fa-youtube"></span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="center box">
                <h2>Address</h2>
                <div class="footer-content">
                    <div class="place">
                        <span class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></span>
                        <span class="text">Cala Bona, Mallorca</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="phone">
                        <span class="fas fa-phone-alt"></span>
                        <span class="text">+34-676841886</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="email">
                        <span class="fas fa-envelope"></span>
                        <span class="text">office@mallorca-now.com</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="right box">
                <h2>Contact Us</h2>
                <div class="footer-content">
                 <form action="#">
                    <div class="email">
                        <div class="text">Email *</div>
                        <input type="email" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="msg">
                        <div class="text">Message *</div>
                        <textarea rows="2" cols="25" required></textarea> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn">
                        <button type="submit">Send</button>
                    </div>
                 </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            <center>
                <span class="credit">Est. 2012 -<a href="#"> Mallorca-Now</a></span>
                <span class="far fa-copyright"></span><span> - All Rights Reserved</span>
            </center>
        
        </div>
    </footer>
    
    <!-- End Footer -->
   
</body>
<!-- InstanceEnd --></html>
```

And my CSS, the last style is the intended "center", but as I have said, I have been having other problems with adding content to the middle section of my site.

````
/* CSS Document */
/* font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; */

*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    text-decoration:none;
    list-style:none;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}



/* Navbar */
nav{
    background-color:#101010;
    height:80px;
    width:100%;
    position:sticky;
    top:0;
}

label.logo{
    color:white;
    font-size:35px;
    font-weight:100;
    line-height:80px;
    padding:0 100px;
}

label.logo span{
    font-weight:900;
}

nav ul{
    float:right;
    margin-right:20px;
}

nav ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    line-height:80px;
    margin:0 5px;
}
    
nav ul li a{
    color:white;
    font-size:17px;
    padding:7px 13px;   
}

nav ul li a.active,nav ul li a:hover{
    background:#6DD5FA;
    transition:0.9s;
    border-radius:4px;
}

.checkbtn{
    font-size:30px;
    color:white;
    float:right;
    line-height:80px;
    margin-right:40px;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:none;
}

#check{
    display:none;
}

@media (max-width: 952px){
    label.logo{
        font-size:30px;
        padding-left:50px;
    }
    nav ul li a{
        font-size:16px;
    }
}
@media (max-width:858px){
    .checkbtn{
        display:block;
    }
    ul{
        position:fixed;
        width:100%;
        height:100vh;
         background-color: #6DD5FA; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
        background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom             right, #2980B9, #6DD5FA, #FFFFFF);
        top:80px;
        left:-100%;
        text-align:center;
        transition:all .9s;
    }
    nav ul li{
        display:block;
        margin:50px;
        line-height:30px;
        
    }
    nav ul li a{
        font-size:20px;
    }
    a:hover,a.active{
        background:none;
        color:#0082e6;
    }
    
    #check:checked ~ ul{
        left:0;
    }
}



/* Main Content */

.main-content{
    
    min-height:;
    background-color: #6DD5FA; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #2980B9, #6DD5FA, #FFFFFF);      
}

.cards{
    max-width:1300px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    padding:30px;
}

.services{
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
}

.cardscontent{
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    flex:1;
    margin:20px;
    padding:20px;
    border:2px solid black;
    border-radius:4px;
    transition: all 0.9s ease;
}

.cardscontent .fab{
    font-size:70px;
    margin:16px 0;
}

.cardscontent .fas{
    font-size:70px;
    margin:16px 0;
}

.cardscontent > *{
    flex: 1 1 100%;
}

.cardscontent:hover{
    color:white;
}

.cardscontent:hover a{
    border-color:white;
    background:white;
    color:black;
}

.c-content1:hover{
    border-color:#BCED91;
    background:#BCED91;
}

.c-content2:hover{
    border-color:#FFC30B;
    background:#FFC30B;
}

.c-content3:hover{
    border-color:#D70040;
    background:#D70040;
}
    

.cardscontent h2{
    font-size:30px;
    margin:16px 0;
    letter-spacing:1px;
}

.cardscontent p{
    font-size:17px;
}

.cardscontent a{
    margin:22px;
    background:black;
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:15px 0;
    border-radius:25px;
    transition:.9s ease;
}

.cardscontent a:hover{
    border-radius:4px;
}

@media (max-width:900px){
    .services{
        display:flex;
        flex-direction:column;
    }
}






/* Footer */

footer{
    position:relative;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#101010;
    color:white;
}

.footer-main-content{
    display:flex;   
}

.footer-main-content .box{
    flex-basis:50%;
    padding:10px 20px;
}

.box h2{
    font-size:1.125rem;
    font-weight:600;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

.box .footer-content{
    margin:20px 0 0 0;
    position:relative;
}

.box .footer-content:before{
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    top:-10px;
    height:2px;
    width:100%;
    background:#1a1a1a;
}

.box .footer-content:after{
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    height:2px;
    width:15%;
    background:#6DD5FA;
    top:-10px;
}

.left .footer-content{
    text-align:justify;
}

.left .footer-content .social{
    margin:20px 0 0 0;
}

.left .footer-content .social a{
    padding: 0 2px;
}

.left .footer-content .social a span{
    height:40px;
    width:40px;
    background:#1a1a1a;
    line-height:40px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:18px;
    border-radius:5px;
    color:white;
}

.left .footer-content .social a span:hover{
    background:#6DD5FA;
    transition:0.9s;
    
}

.center .footer-content .fas{
    font-size:1.4375rem;
    background:#1a1a1a;
    height:45px;
    width:45px;
    line-height:45px;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius:50%;
    transition:0.9s;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.center .footer-content .fas:hover{
    background:#6DD5FA;
}

.center .footer-content .text{
    font-size:1.0625rem;
    font-weight:500;
    padding-left:10px;
}

.center .footer-content .phone{
    margin:10px 0;
}

.right form .text{
    font-size:1.0625rem;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    color:#656565;
}

.right form .msg{
    margin-top:10px;
}

.right form input, .right form textarea{
    width:100%;
    font-size:1.0625rem;
    background:#151515;
    padding-left:10px;
    border:1px solid #222222;
    color:white;
}

.right form input:focus, 
.right form textarea:focus{
    outline-color:#3498db;
}

.right form input{
    height:32px;
}

.right form .btn{
    margin-top:10px;
}

.right form .btn button{
    height:40px;
    width:100%;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
    background: #6DD5FA;
    font-size:1.0625rem;
    font-weight:500;
    cursor:pointer;
    transition:0.3s;
    color:white;
}

.right form .btn button:hover{
    background:#000;
}

.bottom center{
    padding:5px;
    font-size:0.9375rem;
    background:#151515;
}

.bottom center span{
    color:#656565;
}

.bottom center span a{
    color:white;
}

@media screen and (max-width:900px){
    footer{
        position:relative;
        bottom:0px;
    }
    
    .footer-main-content{
        flex-wrap:wrap;
        flex-direction:column;
    }
    
    .footer-main-content .box{
        margin:5px 0;
    }
}


.box-area{
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
} ```

The .box-area should center the content, as I have tried it out in a blank HTML page and it does. I am truly lost. Thanks to anyone that can help, and If I havent provided enough information I am sorry, tell me what you need and I will.

Mark Monaghan
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the reason this is happening is that you are positioning the elements of the navigation bar with float. One of the more bewildering things about working with floats is how they can affect the element that contains them (their “parent” element). To solve the problem, set the overflow property to hidden in nav.

Exemple:

```
nav{
  background-color:#101010;
  height:80px;
  width:100%;
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

You can get more information on how to work with this property through the following link: [All About Floats | CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)

Comment: This also works, due to the fact I have very limited knowledge, I can´t say which I should use and which I shouldn't, but your answer does make me think this is why other tutorials Ive tried to follow didn't work like they should.
Thank you so much, today I learned that StackOverflow is amazingly helpful, and asking questions here actually get answered, I thought I would have to start the whole page from step 1. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to add a width of 100% to the `.box-area` to get it to center.

```
    .box-area{
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    /*Added width to the area and it centered*/
     width: 100%;
}
```

Here is a codepen I used to play with it:
https://codepen.io/josiemedel/pen/XWpMbpw

Comment: Thank you so much, I have upvoted but I cant visibly vote until Im 15 stackoverflow "years" or more!

When I tried to do this on a blank HTML, it worked without the width, do you know why?

Comment: I guess it's because most broswers show <body> with a default of display:block? Source W3Schools